# How to prevent jQuery UI Dialog from stopping other scripts?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, captcha

I'm using jQuery UI's Dialog option to render a pop-up signup form, which contains a captcha.

When I render the signup form on another page, the captcha displays just fine, but it doesn't show up on the Dialog pop-up form.

I checked the HTML, and for whatever reason, only the captcha's 'noscript' code block made it to the page.

Is there something about the jQuery UI Dialog I'm missing that causes it to interfere with other scripts like that?

Here's the form's code:

```
<%= error_messages_for(@user) %>
<%= form_for(:user, :url => users_path, :remote => true, :html => {:id => 'create_user_form'}) do |f| %>
    <div class="in-field">
        <%= f.label(:first_name) %>
        <%= f.text_field(:first_name) %>
        <div class="field_valid"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="in-field">
        <%= f.label(:last_name) %>
        <%= f.text_field(:last_name) %>
        <div class="field_valid"></div>
    </div>
    <%= f.date_select(:birthday, :start_year => 1912) %><br />
    image stuff<br />
    <div class="in-field">
        <%= f.label(:username) %>
        <%= f.text_field(:username) %>
        <div class="field_valid"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="in-field">
        <%= f.label(:password) %>
        <%= f.password_field(:password) %>
        <div class="field_valid"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="in-field">
        <%= f.label(:password_confirmation) %>
        <%= f.password_field(:password_confirmation) %>
        <div class="field_valid"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="in-field">
        <%= f.label(:email) %>
        <%= f.text_field(:email) %>
        <div class="field_valid"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="in-field">
        <%= f.label(:email_confirmation) %>
        <%= f.text_field(:email_confirmation) %>
        <div class="field_valid"></div>
    </div>
        <div id="test">  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfLRdMSAAAAAJ2SYOMT2nNhu2aMw6s3XtD1s5Id"></script>
            </div>
    </div>
    <br />

<%= check_box_tag('eula', 'accepted', false) %> I agree to the <%= link_to('terms of service') %> and <%= link_to('privacy policy') %>.<br />
<%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

And here's the UI pop-up code:

```
$('.modal-dupe').click(function(){
var url = this.href;
$('#modal').remove();
var dialog = $('<div id="modal" style="display:none" class="loading"></div>').prepend('#barhappy_container');
dialog.load(url, function(){
    dialog.dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        position: 'center',
        dialogClass: 'no-title',
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        resizable: false,
        open: function(){
                $.getScript('/assets/modal/in-modal-open.js');
        },
        close: function(event, ui){
            dialog.remove();
        }
    });
});
return false;
```

});

Comment: We might guess or we might see your code please.

Comment: Depending upon your code, you might have initialized the dialog on document load and are rendering it sometime later. This means that your dialog DOM is fully formed on load and any edits you make after that will not be reflected. This is just a guess - but as Mark mentioned above, please post your code for us to help further.

Comment: I apologize. I've added my code...

Comment: Digging around a little bit, it appears there is in fact some part of jQuery UI that stops other scripts from running.
I'll report back after some experimentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, jQuery dialog() can take a function argument when it opens, which I used to call the necessary bit of JavaScript via $.getScript().

You can manually create a Recaptcha using

```
$('SELECTOR FOR AN EMPTY DIV').each(function () {
    Recaptcha.create('YOUR PUBLIC KEY', this
});
```